# How get the width of an input element in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I dont work with a framework, i'm working with JavaScript by default.

I need to know the width of an input text element, in the good browsers i use:

```
width = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "").getPropertyValue('width');
```

But in the f**ing Internet Explorer use:

```
if (typeof el.currentStyle['width'] == "undefined" || el.currentStyle['width'] == 'NaN') {
  width = el.currentStyle['width'];
} else {
  width = null;
}
```

This works, if it is set the width by css or style propertie, but if the size is a default (set by size propertie or dont set) *el.currentStyle['width']* is undefined.

I need to know the width of an element without propertie set.

Comment: voted up for profanity against IE

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171542/proper-ie6-html-element-dimensions

Comment: jQuery manages to magically navigate around this in `.width()` - I don't know how though.

Comment: have you tried `el.offsetWidth`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elwidth= el.offsetWidth+'px';
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use Jquery.  It has .width and .height functions which work in ie6 as well.